# How to use Google Analytics 4 inside chrome extension Manifest V3?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics-4, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

what I found out =>

1. you can't import scripts from links inside chrome extension's background scripts or content scripts (basically anywhere inside new page HTML or popup HTML)
   so you what you need to do is =>

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="./googleAnalytics.js"></script>
    <script src="./googleAnalyticsStarter.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  </body>
</html>
```

instead of =>

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script
      async
      src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXX"
    ></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
      }
      gtag("js", new Date());

      gtag("config", "G-XXXXXXXX");
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app</noscript>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: @Omkar have you found a solution?

Comment: @dee you need to create backend api for each custom event from crx. then backend can dump that event data to ga4 events

Comment: @OmkarBhede yeah, im doing it that way, seems the only way now in extension, tks

Comment: example: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/blob/main/functional-samples/tutorial.google-analytics/README.md